# How to send email a specific data as csv attachment from google sheet?

Tags: javascript

I have google sheet named "Order". In which Order Status (Pending/Cancelled/Done) given in column A, Name in Column B and rest things in C,D,E,F,G.

Now I want that all Pending and Cancelled order detail from Column A to G is emailed automatically.
Is there any script ?

Thanks
Titu Singh